# Mapping routes with web api and angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have two get method on an ApiController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromBody]FileGetModel model)
```

and

```
public List<FileModel> Get([FromBody]MemberFIleSearchModel model)
```

I call this like so:

```
return $http.get(urlBase, { params: args });
```

I get an error returned:

```
"Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
Get on type Api.Controllers.FileUploadController
Get on type Api.Controllers.FileUploadController"
```

Chrome console:

```
GET http://localhost:4345/api/FileUpload/?FileId=5467f90a9fc83d1378c6c8bf&Version=Original_thumb 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I know that both actions have the same name but they are passed in different models so I assume it should be routed correctly.

I have tried using the "Route("GetFile")" attribute but I seem to have an issue referencing the right one or finding the correct namespace. HttpRoute("GetFile") seems to be the only attribute I can get to compile but that doesnt work and I literally cant find any documentation on that attribute.

So i need a solution to either get "Route" to work or make webapi bind to the correct model

Answer (score 0):

You could add a route attribute, such as this example:

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Order> FindOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
}
```

I recommend you to use WebApiRouteDebugger to debug your routes: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/